# How do I define landuse & postalcode for massive data?

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap, land-use, postal-code

I have a PostgreSQL table named `points` where I store nearly **5.6 million** rows of my ping data from a ride-hailing service for AI research purposes. Some of its fields are `latitude`, `longitude`, `landuse`, and `postcode` but the latter two are empty. I want to fill them based on their latitude and longitude. I have tried **[sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/)** and Nominatim both via the **[API](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)** and **[geopy.geolocator](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)** but both take a very long time to manage 5.6 million rows. Here's a little code snippet that uses the geolocator:

```py
for point_id, lat, lon in data:

    location = geolocator.reverse(f'{lat}, {lon}')
    landuse = location.raw.get('type', None)
    postcode = location.raw['address'].get('postcode', None)
    
    update_query = "UPDATE points SET landuse = %s, postalcode = %s WHERE point_id = %s"
    cursor.execute(update_query, (landuse, postcode, point_id))
    conn.commit()
```

This method processes 10 rows in about 6 seconds. The estimated time for this method is 2.8 million seconds, equivalent to almost **778 hours**.

I have also tried using OSM data from **[Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/indonesia.html)** and **[Metro Extracts](https://www.interline.io/osm/extracts/)** for both Jakarta and Indonesia, but the data contains very little landuse and postcode

Is there another way to do it in much less time?

Comment: Use batch reverse geocoding (might be $$$). Depending on where you live you might have a governmental/local free api that can handle batch geocoding/reverse geocoding (example: [French governmental API](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api-doc/adresse) does handle csv batch geocoding forward and reverse). But basically, you want do everything in batches, your reverse geocoding and your updating.

Comment: As for the *landUSE* it depends a lot on your area. There are many global *landCOVER* data-sets, if that is usefull, or if you have landuse data availalbe for your region, I would suggest to simply download it and sample the LU/LC at the respective points locations on your device, which should be rather quick. One possible data-product with good global accuracy and recent update is the ESA World Cover: https://esa-worldcover.org/en/data-access.